# Zoom/unzoom and points decimation

Tags: c#, mschart

Situation:

I have one Chart and three ChartArea that are aligned in view, zoom, cursor through the AxisViewChanged method that act in this way:

```
       if (e.Axis == ax1)
        {
            ax2.ScaleView.Size = ax1.ScaleView.Size;
            ax2.ScaleView.Position = ax1.ScaleView.Position;
            ax3.ScaleView.Size = ax1.ScaleView.Size;
            ax3.ScaleView.Position = ax1.ScaleView.Position;
            min = (int)ax1.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
            max = (int)ax1.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;         
        }

        if (e.Axis == ax2)
        { 
        ....
```

And it works very well in both cases: when I zoom in/out or scroll.

Problem:

The problem is that my graph source is made by a lot of points, in the worst case we talk about 3'600'000 samples. With this amount of samples, when I move around points with cursor and try to show a tooltip with the values, the interaction quality collapse and becomes unusables (even having set Fast Line). 
So I tried to implement a simple decimation algorithm to reducethe number of showed points:

```
  void draw_graph(int start, int end)
    {
        double fract_value = 0;
        int int_value = 0;
        int num_saples_selected = end - start;
        if(num_saples_selected <= MAX_GRAPH_NUM_SAMPLES)
            fill_graphs_point(0, end, 1);
        else
        {
            fract_value = ((double)num_saples_selected) / ((double)MAX_GRAPH_NUM_SAMPLES);
            int_value = (int)fract_value;
            if (fract_value > int_value)                
                int_value++;                                    
            fill_graphs_point(0, end, int_value);
        }
    }

    void fill_graphs_point(int start, int end, int step)
    {
        int i = 0;          
        for (i = start; i < end; i=i+step)
        {
           dlChart.Series[SERIES_VOLTAGE].Points.AddXY(timestamps_array[i], voltage_array[i]);                                                    
           dlChart.Series[SERIES_CURRENT].Points.AddXY(timestamps_array[i], current_array[i]);               
           dlChart.Series[SERIES_ENERGY].Points.AddXY(timestamps_array[i], energy_array[i]);

         // I will use this to came back to real position of the initial array
            decimation_positions.Add(i);
        }
    }
```

Assuminig I had a good idea with this method to reduce the points number, I do not know where to put the call to the function "draw_graph". If I put it in the AxisViewChanged method it will call my method also when I scroll (horizontally) my graph and this is not what I want. I want to call my method only on zoom and unzoom event.

Expected behavior: in the first view (without any zoom) the graph has to show an "idea" of the trend of the graph. Then for every selection/(un)zoom I want to call my function to check if the points number of selected portion will fit in my window size that is MAX_GRAPH_NUM_SAMPLES(=10000).

Hope someone can help me. Whatever kind of suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is never a good reason to dump that many points into a chart, nobody has a monitor that big.  Just *always* filter the data before you create the series.

Comment: Thank you Hans, in this way I try to filter the points to reduce their number. Maybe I was not so clear: in the first view (without any zoom) the grpah has to show an "idea" of the trend of the graph. Then for every selection/(un)zoom I want to call my function to check if the points number of selected portion will fit in my window size that is (MAX_GRAPH_NUM_SAMPLES=10000)

Comment: There is an `AxisViewChanged` which I would use to determine if we need to prepare for zooming in or out by changing the Points collection to some other set of data. But there are other UI solutions, which are less difficult to code. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=tsla+stock) for an example which users will find acceptable.. The (German) tabs go from 1Day to 5Years and Max..

Comment: In any case I soved

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say that strangely the problem appeared when I zoomed in more than one time. At some point also the PC fan started. I resolved disabling the library zoom and implement my self a sort of zoom (a little bit more simple). The solution is in this method and the method I write in the question:

```
private void dlChart_SelectionRangeChange(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
    {
        double startSelection = e.NewSelectionStart;
        double endSelection = e.NewSelectionEnd;

        // Allow the selection to disappear
        reset_selection();
        try
        {
            // before convert point from "showed point" to "real point" I check the limits
            if (
              (startSelection >= 0) && (startSelection <= decimation_positions.Count()) &&
              (endSelection >= 0) && (endSelection <= decimation_positions.Count()) &&
              (endSelection != startSelection)
            )
            {
                // convert
                startSelection = decimation_positions[(int)startSelection];
                endSelection = decimation_positions[(int)endSelection];
                // check for reverse zoom (from right to left)
                if (startSelection > endSelection)
                {
                    double tmp = startSelection;
                    startSelection = endSelection;
                    endSelection = tmp;
                }
                // clean the series
                this.reset_series();
                // draw the selected range
                draw_graph((int)startSelection, (int)endSelection);
            }
        }catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            // todo
        }


        //System.Console.WriteLine("SelSTART = "+e.NewSelectionStart+" SelEND = "+e.NewSelectionEnd);

    }
```